# Image Slider not working only on Magento Frontend Homepage

Tags: javascript, image, frontend, slider

I am trying to solve an issue that I do not even know when started. My general frontend template has a image slides on the right column. All internal pages of my website show the image slider without problems, however the homepage hides the slides. If you use the chrome inspection, all the elements are there, but not visible. Any idea of how to solve this?

Homepage: http://lojaanalitica.com.br/

Example of internal page: http://lojaanalitica.com.br/combos.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the links they are super helpful! 
Looks like on the homepage you have some JavaScript errors this would cause your slider to not initialize on the homepage hence why its hidden.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery('.flexsliderdd').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});s
```

Remove the `s` Also its outputting a typeError that `sequence` is not a function
`var homeSequence = $("#homeslider-sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");`

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I removed the "s" and looked for the need of that last line, the code do not even use the varible homeSequence. I commented the line and the problem was solved, also installed a javascript debug for chrome for future issues, thx for your help =)

Comment: @FelyppeRodrigues No Problems :) Just an FYI chrome already has an inbuilt javascript debugger in the developer tools.